# create-react-app retornando erro 'Cannot find module 'react-scripts/scripts/init.js' '

Tags: node.js, react, npm, yarn

Quando tento realizar a criação do projeto de react tanto com o npm como com o yarn (create-react-app teste), ele retorna o seguinte erro:

```
 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts/scripts/init.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at [eval]:2:20
        at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:122:20)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:329:38)
        at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
        at evalScript (internal/bootstrap/node.js:589:27)

    Aborting installation.
      node  has failed.

    Deleting generated file... node_modules
    Deleting generated file... package.json
    Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
    Deleting teste/ from C:\Users\Laura\Documents\STUDY\React
    Done.
```

Desinstalei e instalei algumas vezes para ter a certeza de que estaria tudo atualizado, porém ainda continuo com o mesmo erro.

node -v : v10.16.0 || npm -v  : 6.9.0 || yarn -v : 1.16.0

Comment: Qual versão do create-react-app? Sistema operacional windows, mac ou linux?

Comment: create-react-app 3.0.1 e  Windows 10

Comment: Você instalou globalmente o create-react-app? No windows a pasta global fica em AppData, remove tudo do pc e apaga as pastas npm que fica em AppData e entao tenta novamente.

Comment: Sim, globalmente e já reinstalei tudo também :/

Comment: Tenso, uma saída e tu criar a estrutura manualmente sem scaffold, instalando o react e o react-dom, configurar todos os plugins do webpack. [Exemplo](https://dev.to/vish448/create-react-project-without-create-react-app-3goh)